# Can't activate/deactivate QuickEdit mode

Tags: bash

I am suddenly unable to access the settings so that I can switch off/on the Quick Edit mode. Previously, I used to be able to do this by right clicking (possibly the ribbon at top of screen) and clicking the tick box on and off. But now right-clicking does not generate any thing.
Thanks for any help!

C